# Spark 1.0.1 installation error

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop2, emr

I keep facing this error on my spark 1.0.1 installation [EMR]

Hadoop version : 2.2
Spark : 1.0.1

Error

14/10/21 06:58:11 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: no hadoop in java.library.path
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hadoop in java.library.path

I tried like this , but it still fails...

./spark-shell -Djava.library.path=/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common

Any suggestion is highly appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about this warning. You can just ignore it. If you feel unconformable with it, you can point `java.library.path` to `$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native`.

Comment: i did that too...like Dspark.library.path=/home/hadoop/lib/native but it still throws the same error...

Comment: Use `--driver-java-options`, such as `./spark-shell --driver-java-options "-Djava.library.path=${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native"`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue was due to just early builds on EMR. Please try with the latest builds as described at https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/tree/master/spark as installation and versions have improved greatly since 1.0.1.